# binding with es6 classes and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

working on a project I notice that `this` in class methods is not really attached to the instance, nor even the class, when accessed through jquery calls. Instead it is the `window` global that I am seeing, and that's not right.

So there are various methods to autobind that for you.. I tried a couple, and  -- not with success. What is going on?

Here's the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.chooseAtRandom is not a function
    at move (pen.js:83)
move @ pen.js:83
pen.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at UIController.animate (pen.js:102)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (pen.js:131)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
animate @ pen.js:102
(anonymous) @ pen.js:131
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
pen.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: this.chooseAtRandom is not a function
    at move (pen.js:83)
```

Here's my autobind method:

```
class Binder {
  getAllMethods(instance, cls) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance))
    .filter(name => {
      let method = instance[name]
      return !(!(method instanceof Function) || method === cls)
    })
  }
  bind(instance, cls) {
  Binder.getAllMethods(instance, cls)
    .forEach(mtd => {
      instance[mtd] = instance[mtd].bind(instance);
    })
  }
}
```

Note the `Binder.getAllMethods` call in there. If I change that to `this.getAllMethods` I get a problem here too. I'm wondering if codepen is breaking it

And here's me using it:

```
class SimonAudio {
  constructor() {
    this.soundsrcs = [
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3',
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3',
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3',
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3'
    ]
    this.players = this.soundsrcs.map(s => {
      let a = document.createElement('audio');
      a.setAttribute('src', s)
      return a
    })
    this.uiMap = {
      red: 0,
      green: 1,
      amarillo: 2,
      blue: 3
    }

    Binder.bind(this, SimonAudio)
  }
  play(uiId) {
    this.players[this.uiMap[uiId]].play()
  }
}

class Game {
  constructor(UI) {
    this.UI = UI
    this.uiMap = {
      red: 0,
      green: 1,
      amarillo: 2,
      blue: 3
    };
    this.dexUi = ['red', 'green', 'amarillo', 'blue']
    this.states = ['SHOWINGCHALLENGE', 'LISTENING']
    this.audio = new SimonAudio()
    this.moves = []
    this.gameStack = []
    this.inGame = false

    Binder.bind(this, Game)
  }

  start() {
    this.inGame = true
    this.gameStack.push(setTimeout(this.move, parseInt((Math.random() + 1) * 1000)))
  }
  restart() {
    this.moves = []
    this.gameStack.forEach(a => {
      clearTimeout(a)
    })
    this.gameStack = []
    this.inGame = false
  }
  playMoves() {
    let elf = this.UI
    this.moves.forEach(m =>
      this.gameStack.push(
        setTimeout(function() {
          elf.animate(m)
        }, parseInt((Math.random() + 1) * 500)))
    )
  }
  move() {
    let move = this.chooseAtRandom()
    this.moves.push(move)
    this.playMoves()
  }
  chooseAtRandom() {
    return this.dexUi[parseInt(Math.random() * 4)]
  }
}

class UIController {
  contructor() {
    this.animation_stack = []
    Binder.bind(this, UIController)
  }
  clear() {
    this.animation_stack.forEach(a => clearTimeout(a))
    this.animation_stack = []
  }
  animate(uiId) {
    $(`#${uiId}`).addClass('highlight')
    this.animation_stack.push(setTimeout(function() {
      $(`#${uiId}`).removeClass('highlight')
    }, 333))
  }
}
```

Then the jquery that is blowing that up:

```
$(function() {
  let UI = new UIController()
  let Simon = new Game(UI)

  $('#strict').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled')
  })

  $('#restart').click(function() {
    $('.controls .button').removeClass('disabled toggled')
    $('.game-buttons div').addClass('disabled')
    Simon.restart()
  })

  $('#start').click(function() {
    if (Game.inGame)
      return
    $('.game-buttons > div').addClass('hvr-radial-out')
    $(this).addClass('toggled')
    $('#strict').addClass('disabled')
    $('.game-buttons div').removeClass('disabled')
    Simon.start()
  })

  $('.game-buttons div').addClass('disabled')
    .click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        return
      let id = $(this).attr('id')
      UI.animate(id)
      Simon.audio.play(id)
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding as I understand it is typically used to bind a function or multiple functions to an object.

For example using JS's bind:

```
this.start.bind(this);
```

Or using lodash's bind/bindAll:

```
_.bind(this.start, this);
_.bindAll(this, ['start', 'restart']);
```

"this" in these cases would refer to an instance of the Game class. I believe this would ensure the bound method(s) would always be called within the context of the game instance.

Your approach doesn't quite appear to follow this usage.

I recommend using the lodash bind/bindAll implementations rather than trying to roll your own.

**Resources**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#bind
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#bindAll

P.S. That's awesome you're making a Simon game!

Comment: it seems to very closely follow the `boundGetX` example.. in what significant way is it different?

Comment: ```var boundGetX = retrieveX.bind(module);``` -- in the boundGetX example an object is being bound to a function (retrieveX). ```Binder.bind(this, Game)``` -- in your example you're trying to bind an object to a class (Binder).

Comment: Sorry I hadn't properly looked through your Binder code. I think I might see what you're trying to do now.

Comment: No I thank you, but you didnt read the code correctly. I am binding the class methods. `Binder.bind` is a custom method that handles that binding for each method or property of the object, for whatever class it is given, I got that from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anhldbk/782e13de7f79b07e556a029a9ce49fa3) and it might not be right but it looks about right.. but that's what Im trying to get to work.

Comment: at this point I've discerned that it is exclusively at the `setTimeout` calls. the one to `move` in particular, makes a call to `Game.move` .. which in turn references an internal object `Game.UI` which is a `UIController`

I can _almost fix it by calling the timeout like: `setTimeout(function(){ self.move.bind(this)` ... using self.. but then in `move()` there is a call to `Game.UI.animate()` and `this` remains bound

Comment: I don't know whether it's a requirement for you to have a custom bind implementation but I think I got the game working by replacing your custom code with lodash's bind and bindAll methods. The start and restart buttons appear to be working anyway: https://codepen.io/david_i_smith/pen/rWRdLr?editors=0011. IMO, it's often better to use native or third-party methods for stuff like bind than try and roll your own, not that there's anything wrong with trying.

Comment: - no, its no requirement, I grabbed that because a couple of others on npm I had even less luck with. Your works! commute that last comment up to your answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @robertotomás I just added the recommendation to use the lodash methods. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.chooseAtRandom is not a function

OK, well let's look at the calling code

```
move() {
  let move = this.chooseAtRandom()
  this.moves.push(move)
  this.playMoves()
}
```

OK, let's look at the calling code for `move` now

```
start() {
  this.inGame = true
  this.gameStack.push(setTimeout(this.move, parseInt((Math.random() + 1) * 1000)))
}
```

OK, right there you lose the `this` context you hope to preserve when the function actually fires. We can easily rewrite this in a couple of ways. But before I start copying/pasting another really bad part of your code, I have to fix that first.

```
// parseInt is for converting strings to numbers
// Math.random() gives you a number so you don't need to parse it
// change this
parseInt((Math.random() + 1) * 1000)

// to this
(Math.random() + 1) * 1000
```

OK, now let's fix your function context

```
// Option 1: use Function.prototype.bind
this.gameStack.push(setTimeout(this.move.bind(this), (Math.random() + 1) * 1000))

// Option 2: use a sexy ES6 arrow function
this.gameStack.push(setTimeout(() => this.move(), (Math.random() + 1) * 1000))
```

OK, now let's check if `start` is called with the proper context

```
$('#start').click(function() {
  if (Game.inGame)
    return
  $('.game-buttons > div').addClass('hvr-radial-out')
  $(this).addClass('toggled')
  $('#strict').addClass('disabled')
  $('.game-buttons div').removeClass('disabled')
  Simon.start()
})
```

OK ! The `this` in your `start` function will be set to the `Simon` instance of `Game`. I can't run the rest of your code so I don't know if there are other problems, but that should fix the `this.chooseAtRandom` is not a function error you were seeing before.

OK.

Comment: that's good, really is, thanks. I had just found this talking to the other guy who answered so far. But two lines down from the call to `moves()` that you address, is a call to `playMoves` which references an internal `UIController`. That is also firing setTimeout calls, but changing them in the analogous fashtion doesn't resolve the issue: `      this.gameStack.push(
        setTimeout(function() {
          elf.animate(m).bind(elf)
        }, parseInt((Math.random() + 1) * 500)))`

Comment: Is there some guide you're following to make this or are you making up these classes on your own? The auto-binding is extremely messy and likely the cause of other problems I cannot readily see.

Comment: Im not following a guide, no. I dont see why you think that is messy. I did get that from someone's [gist post](https://gist.github.com/anhldbk/782e13de7f79b07e556a029a9ce49fa3).. I'm not attached to it in any case, especially since it doesn;t seem to resolve nested classes like this. anyway, other guy found a working solution. going with lodash

Comment: @robertotomás for one, you implemented `Binder` differently than in that gist. That gist has static class methods for `getAllMethods` and `bind` whereas yours is implemented with instance methods. Second, I feel as tho auto-binding is for those that don't really understand dynamic function contexts very well; ie it's dreadful to image it's *necessary* to bind *every single method* in *every single class* to a known context just to write a simple game. For what it's worth (not much), I haven't used `Function.prototype.bind` in production code in almost 2 years. It's just not *that* essential.

Comment: ... If you're relying on it so heavily, I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding of how JavaScript works. Third, this is the most brain-twisting propositional logic expression I've seen in a while: `!(!(method instanceof Function) || method === cls);` – that can be expressed in a much more straightforward way as `method instanceof Function && method !== cls;` – see also: [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: "ie it's dreadful to image" haha, you deserve a break, good friend. you're obviously drunk